# Avoid auto URL encoding in query parameters using RestKit

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, restkit

I need to make a GET request like this:
http://myurl.com/api/v1/endpoint?query=my+search+term where `my+search+term` is user input from a `UITextField`, except the users would put spaces instead of `+` signs.

```
let query = myTextField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+").lowercased()
RKObjectManager.shared()
.getObject(nil, 
           path: "/endpoint/",
           parameters: ["query": query],
           success: {(op: RKObjectRequestOperation?, result: RKMappingResult?) in},
           failure: {(op: RKObjectRequestOperation?, error: Error?) in})
```

Checking the server log, I see that RestKit is trying to URL encode my query parameters like this. How can I get around this?

```
[09/Jul/2017 21:39:04] "GET /endpoint?query=my%2Bsearch%2Bterm HTTP/1.1" 200 96
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't replace " " with "+" and let RestKit take care of it?

Comment: Fortunately, the server accepts `my%20search%20term` so yes. But just for my education (and possibly others'), the question still stands.